# What control will be best for Buddy List?

Tags: c#, .net, controls, chat, xmpp

I'm developing a xmpp chat client in C#.NET. I'm little confused about what control should I use for Buddy list. Buddy list will consist of status icon, name & his buddy pic. Can u please recommend that what control will be best for me to use? (Do u think that ListView will be appropriate?)

Another question, I'm using agsxmpp. Does it support invisible status in Gtalk. Is there any library out there bettre than this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ListView would be fine, it supports everything you would need. You could also go with an owner-draw ListBox if you want something with a little more flexibility (though obviously, that'd be more work).

As for your other question, I'm not sure. You might want to check the documentation for the library.

Comment: From the selection of controls in the .NET Framework, ListView is indeed the way to go. You can also custom draw the icon and do whatever you'd like. Grouping is nice, and drag & drop requires a little code but it's worth it (moving a buddy from one group to another, reordering buddies, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Using TreeView will be the best control, it will help you in grouping buddies. I used it before for the same purpose.

Comment: Thank u very much for ur answer.
I think u can do grouping in ListView too. :) But TreeView doesn't fulfill my other requirements(How I'm going to insert buddy icon and status icon for each buddy?)

Answer (score 0):

The [RosterTree](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/source/browse/trunk/muzzle/RosterTree.cs) code in Jabber-Net would be a good starting point.  It already does owner-draw, and could be pretty easily extended to do avatars by modifying the DrawItem method.